# Brute force sudoku solving in Haskell

Tags: haskell, backtracking

So I'm currently writing a Sudoku solver and have to create the solve function.
Given:

```
solve :: Sudoku -> [Maybe Sudoku]
```

where Sudoku's are `[[Maybe Int]]`.

This is to be solved by brute force, so I recursively check for whether the sudoku can be solved, whether it's full but breaks constraints (such as repeated numbers in a row/column/block) and otherwise, insert 1-9 recursively in first found blank spot until it works or until I know it will never work.

The problem arises when, say the first blank space I find accepts 1 as it's new input, but then later realizes that this won't work, then I have to go back and change that 1 to a 2, or whichever works next and try solving again. How do I go about this? Here's the current code I have for solving:

```
solve :: Sudoku -> [Maybe Sudoku]
solve sud
    | isSudoku sud && isSolved sud && isOkay sud = [Just sud]
    | isSudoku sud && isSolved sud && not (isOkay sud) = [Nothing]
    | isSudoku sud && not (isSolved sud) = solve (helper sud (blank sud) False 1)

helper :: Sudoku -> Pos -> Bool -> Int -> Sudoku
helper sud pos check n
    | n > 9 || n < 1 || check = sud
    | n > 0 && n < 10 && not check = 
        do
            let newSud = (update sud pos (Just n))
            helper newSud pos (isOkay newSud) (n+1)
```

Any inputs on how to go about this?

Edit: Sudoku is implemented as:

```
data Sudoku = Sudoku [[Maybe Int]]
deriving ( Eq )
```

For the feedback I've gotten so far, the code above already solves sudokus. The issue is for when there are enough blank spots that a certain spot could accept multiple numbers rather than only working with one. Say a blank spot works with the number 5 and 8, but 8 is the right answer and 5 makes it unsolvable. Then I have to go back and change it and try solving all the next blanks again.

Comment: You should include the definition of your `Sudoku` type.

Answer (score 1):

this is really broad but basically for this kind of algorithm the list-monad is your friend ;) - also you don't need the Maybe in there if you just represent the case where you cannot find a solution with []

Here is *pseudo-code* for it:

```
solve :: Sudoku -> [Sudoku]
solve sud
    | isSudoku sud && isSolved sud && isOkay sud = [sud]
    | isSudoku sud && isSolved sud && not (isOkay sud) = []
    | isSudoku sud && not (isSolved sud) = do
       nr <- [1..9]
       let sud' = sud `updateNextUnsetCellWith` nr
       solve sud'
```

of course you have to write the `updateNextUnsetCellWith` function first - it should just set `nr` into the first unset cell and return the updated state and of course it assumes that the other two cases will trigger if there are no unset cells.

**Please Note** this brute-force variant will drive you insane at it will take *a very long time* to produce results for reasonable problems.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked your code, but in general you have to act as if there is more than one solution and you try to find them all. This means at any time you iterate over all possible choices, where a choice is `(Cell, Integer)`.

So you enter the first choice, which gives you a more complete sudoku,  and then try to solve the new sudoku in the same fashion. This results in either a solved sudoku or at some point you run out of choices before the sudoko is complete. So at any point you receive either a solved sudoku or an indication that there is no solution. In the latter case you try the next choice until the sudoku is solved or you run out of choices yourself and you return an indication that there is no solution along this path.

As a side note: When I tried this method, I had to realize that brute foce is too slow. You get acceptable performance when you order your choices such that you first try those cells  with the smallest number of choices.

Another side note: to test this, you can take a solved sudoku and remove one number and see if the solution is found. Then you remove two number etc.